# Can I make a calculation with a value outside of the range of my variable?

Tags: c, range, uint8t

I'm coding in C and I know the values that can be stored in a `uint8_t` range from 0 to 255. I want to store a value that is the percentage of `MAX_INTENSITY`, declared as:
`#define MAX_INTENSITY 200`

Can I do the following:
`uint8_t my_intensity = (MAX_INTENSITY * percentage) / 100;` ?

The result will be 200 or less, but during the calculation, the intermediate result can be superior to 255, e.g. with `percentage = 50`, `MAX_INTENSITY * percentage` = 10'000. Can this cause a problem, even if the final result will be 100, o in the range of a `uint8_t`?

Comment: The sub-expression `MAX_INTENSITY * percentage` will be calculated as `int`s throughout. Same as `(MAX_INTENSITY * percentage) / 100`. See [C11 6.3.1.1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.1) and [C11 6.3.1.8](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.8)

Comment: Thanks. Would it be the case even if ```percentage``` and ```MAX_INTENSITY``` were variables declared as ```uint8_t``` ?

Comment: Yes, both values will be converted to `int` before the expression is evaluated... and converted back to the smaller type afterwards.

Comment: I don't really know assembler, but ==> https://godbolt.org/z/76ff8xdv8 <== lines 5,7: full 32-bit operations; lines 12,13: 8-bit operations

Comment: It is sometimes necessary to explicitly convert operands to a wider integer type to avoid arithmetic overflow during rational scaling operations, but it is not necessary in this case.

Answer (score 2):

In C, the rules to determine the type used for each intermediary computation are somewhat intricate, but for your particular case quite easy:

The multiplication `MAX_INTENSITY * percentage` involves an integer constant `200` of type `int` and a variable `percentage`. If the type of `percentage` is `int` or a smaller type such as `uint8_t`, this operand will undergo an *integer promotion* to type `int` and the result will have type `int`, then used as an operand for the division by `100`, another integer constant with type `int`, hence a computation with type `int` and a result of the same type. The result will be converted to the type of the destination, `uint8_t`, which is performed by take the positive modulo 256, a fully defined operation, especially if `percentage` is known to be in range `0` to `200`.

Therefore, your definition is correct:

```
uint8_t my_intensity = (MAX_INTENSITY * percentage) / 100;
```

You might nevertheless consider using type `int` for this local variable, as there is no benefit in typing it with a smaller type in this context.